java.io.FileNotFoundException: serenity.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
I am trying to run my automation tests on my Windows laptop. I've configured the system variables for Java (17.0.4.1) and Gradle (8.7) correctly. My automation framework is a Serenity framework using BDD, and I'm using IntelliJ to run my builds. The build.gradle files contain all the necessary settings. However, every time I run the build, the executeTest task fails with the error: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: serenity.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)." I'm unsure how to fix this issue since the same code and settings work fine on another machine. Please guide me.
Error while executing Tests

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':executeTest'.


java.io.FileNotFoundException: serenity.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 2m 1s
13 actionable tasks: 13 executed

enter image description here
enter image description here

As the exception suggests, have you tried finding this serenity.properties file on your system? It's possible that despite having the same code and settings, this other machine has the properties file and your computer doesn't.
